# java.lang.RuntimeException: , java.lang.IllegalStateException: crash report in google play console

Tags: android, android-activity, google-play-console

I am really confused how these crashes are coming, as i have tested in real Oreo device and the app is working smoothly without crash but in google play console report i have 34.92k crashes for Android 8.0 , 8.1 Devices.

crash report from Play consolole  java.lang.RuntimeException:

```
  java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver 
(ActivityThread.java:3194)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap17 (Unknown Source)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage 
(ActivityThread.java:1672)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:164)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6501)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run 
(RuntimeInit.java:460)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

crash report from Play consolole  java.lang.IllegalStateException:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
  at android.app.ContextImpl.startServiceCommon (ContextImpl.java:1521)
  at android.app.ContextImpl.startService (ContextImpl.java:1477)
  at android.content.ContextWrapper.startService 
(ContextWrapper.java:650)
  at android.content.ContextWrapper.startService 
(ContextWrapper.java:650)
  at com.myapp.package.service.BootReceiver.receive 
(BootReceiver.kt:39)
  at com.myapp.package.service.CoreReceiver.onReceive 
(CoreReceiver.java:62)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver (ActivityThread.java:3187)
```

my code for BootReceiver

```
     } else if (FIRE_INTENT == action) {
         val alarmedIntent = intent.getParcelableExtra<Intent> 
   (ALARMED_INTENT)
        val alarmedAction = alarmedIntent.action
        Timber.i("BootReceiver Got alarm to fire alarmedIntent %s", 
alarmedAction)
        alarmedIntent.putExtra(CoreReceiver.WAKE_LOCK_ID, tmpWakeLockId)
        tmpWakeLockId = null
        context.startService(alarmedIntent)
    } else if (SCHEDULE_INTENT == action) {
        val atTime = intent.getLongExtra(AT_TIME, -1)
        val alarmedIntent = intent.getParcelableExtra<Intent> 
 (ALARMED_INTENT)
        Timber.i("BootReceiver Scheduling intent %s for %tc", 
alarmedIntent, atTime)

        val pi = buildPendingIntent(context, intent)
        val alarmMgr = K9AlarmManager.getAlarmManager(context)

        alarmMgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, atTime, pi)
    }
```

for CoreReceiver

```
@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Integer tmpWakeLockId = CoreReceiver.getWakeLock(context);
    try {
        Timber.i("CoreReceiver.onReceive %s", intent);

        if (CoreReceiver.WAKE_LOCK_RELEASE.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            Integer wakeLockId = intent.getIntExtra(WAKE_LOCK_ID, -1);
            if (wakeLockId != -1) {
                Timber.v("CoreReceiver Release wakeLock %d", 
         wakeLockId);
                CoreReceiver.releaseWakeLock(wakeLockId);
            }
        } else {
            tmpWakeLockId = receive(context, intent, tmpWakeLockId);
        }
    } finally {
        CoreReceiver.releaseWakeLock(tmpWakeLockId);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't use `startService` if your app is not in the foreground, use `startForegroundService()` - https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background#services

Comment: Dear Mark will you please provide me a example ? if i am changing startService to startForegroundService() it will affect bellow 8.0 devices as the app is available minimum sdk 24

Comment: Use `ContextCompat.startForegroundService()`

Comment: Problem solved with ths   if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                context.startForegroundService(Intent(context, BootReceiver::class.java))
            } else {
                context.startService(alarmedIntent)
            }

Comment: That's exactly what `ContextCompat.startForegroundService()` does ..